# Reset seed for each foreign key field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created 2 tables, Header and Lines:

```
CREATE TABLE HEADER 
(
HeaderId int IDENTITY (1,1),
HeaderName varchar(20)
CONSTRAINT pk_header PRIMARY KEY (HeaderId)
);

CREATE TABLE Lines
(
LineId int IDENTITY (1,1),
HeaderId int REFERENCES HEADER(HeaderId),
LineName varchar(20)
CONSTRAINT pk_header_line PRIMARY KEY (LineId, HeaderId)
)
```

This is what my Lines table looks like after inserting some data:

```
LineId  HeaderId    LineName
1       1           Header1 Line1
2       1           Header1 Line2
3       2           Header2 Line1
```

Is there any possibility that LineId starts at 1 when HeaderId changes?

Something like this:

```
LineId  HeaderId    LineName
1       1           Header1 Line1
2       1           Header1 Line2
1       2           Header2 Line1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism for that.
You could add a `lines int` column to your HEADER table which holds the number of lines per header, with default 0.
When you insert a record into Lines you should use HEADER.lines + 1 for LineId and increase HEADER.lines by 1.
You can do it via your application by or using a trigger for inserts on Lines.
In any case take in consideration that deletes on Lines will break the sequence.

```
create table header 
(
    headerid    int         identity (1,1) constraint header_pk_headerid primary key
   ,headername  varchar (20)
   ,lines       int         not null    default (0)
)


create table lines
(
    lineid      int         not null
   ,headerid    int         not null    constraint lines_fk_headerid references header(headerid)
   ,linename    varchar (20)
   ,constraint lines_pk_headerid_lineid primary key (lineid, headerid)
)

go

create trigger lines_trg_ins  
on lines
instead of insert
as  

    declare @lines table (headerid int,lines int)

    update  h
    set     h.lines = h.lines + i.lines
    output  deleted.headerid,deleted.lines into @lines
    from            header as h 
            join    (select headerid,count(*) as lines from inserted group by headerid) as i
            on      i.headerid = h.headerid

    insert into lines (lineid,headerid,linename)
    select  row_number() over (partition by i.headerid order by getdate()) + l.lines,l.headerid,i.linename
    from    inserted i join @lines l on l.headerid = i.headerid
```

---

```
insert into header (headername) values ('header1'),('header2')
insert into lines (headerid,linename) values (1,'header1 line1'),(1,'header1 line2'),(1,'header1 line3'),(2,'header2 line1'),(2,'header2 line2')
```

---

```
select * from header
```

---

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| headerid | headername | lines |
+----------+------------+-------+
| 1        | header1    | 3     |
+----------+------------+-------+
| 2        | header2    | 2     |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

---

```
select * from lines order by headerid,lineid
```

---

```
+--------+----------+---------------+
| lineid | headerid | linename      |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| 1      | 1        | header1 line1 |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| 2      | 1        | header1 line2 |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| 3      | 1        | header1 line3 |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| 1      | 2        | header2 line1 |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| 2      | 2        | header2 line2 |
+--------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!